# Coinbase API for PHP: Undefined index: pagination returned by $client->getAccounts()

Tags: php, api, coinbase-api

After clean install of the Coinbase API for PHP on my Xubuntu 16.04 (composer require coinbase/coinbase) I followed the Coinbase documentation and used the following commands to access my wallet:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Coinbase\Wallet\Client;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration;
$apiKey =  '********';
$apiSecret =  '*********';
$configuration = Configuration::apiKey($apiKey, $apiSecret);
$client = Client::create($configuration);
$accounts = $client->getAccounts();
...
...
```

The function getAccounts always returns:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: pagination in /home/willem/coinbase/vendor/coinbase/coinbase/src/Mapper.php on line 490
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/willem/coinbase/newfile.php:0
PHP   2. Coinbase\Wallet\Client->getAccounts() /home/willem/coinbase/newfile.php:14
PHP   3. Coinbase\Wallet\Client->getAndMapCollection() /home/willem/coinbase/vendor/coinbase/coinbase/src/Client.php:215
PHP   4. Coinbase\Wallet\Mapper->toAccounts() /home/willem/coinbase/vendor/coinbase/coinbase/src/Client.php:834
PHP   5. Coinbase\Wallet\Mapper->toCollection() /home/willem/coinbase/vendor/coinbase/coinbase/src/Mapper.php:59
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: pagination in /home/willem/coinbase/vendor/coinbase/coinbase/src/Mapper.php on line 491
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/willem/coinbase/newfile.php:0
PHP   2. Coinbase\Wallet\Client->getAccounts() /home/willem/coinbase/newfile.php:14
PHP   3. Coinbase\Wallet\Client->getAndMapCollection() /home/willem/coinbase/vendor/coinbase/coinbase/src/Client.php:215
PHP   4. Coinbase\Wallet\Mapper->toAccounts() /home/willem/coinbase/vendor/coinbase/coinbase/src/Client.php:834
PHP   5. Coinbase\Wallet\Mapper->toCollection() /home/willem/coinbase/vendor/coinbase/coinbase/src/Mapper.php:59
```

Despite the error, the account information is retrieved into $accounts.
Obviously I now use 2>/dev/null but I'd rather not.
Any solution is highly appreciated !

Comment: It's a notice, not an error. The Coinbase code isn't written cleanly, it's referencing a variable that doesn't exist. You can ignore notices via `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested line of code indeed suppresses the 'notice', as per Alex's comment.
I'm a happy coder again :)